# Move the light over z-axis

Tags: c++, opengl, light

I’m trying to make my light move around the z-axis and make a complete tour, but I get only half a tour. This is what I wrote:

```
float value=0;
LightPos.z = cos(value) + sin (value);
value+=0.2;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you want to rotate the light around the z-axis, you need to calculate the x and y coordinate depending on the angle: `x = radius * cos(angle);` `y = radius * sin(angle);`

Comment: What are ```raduis``` and ```angle``` in your case?

Comment: !? Anything you want. `angle = value`. The radius is the distance of the light source to the z-axis.